# spark: dataframe.count yields way more rows than printing line by line or show()

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

New to Spark; using Databricks. Really puzzled.

I have this dataFrame: df.

`df.count()` yields Long = 5460

But if I print line by line: 
`df.collect.foreach(println)` I get only 541 rows printed out. Similarly, `df.show(5460)` only shows 1017 rows. What could be the reason?

A related question: how can I save "df" with Databricks? And where does it save to? -- I tried to save before but couldn't find the file afterwards. I load the data by mounting an S3 bucket, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question, Databricks output truncates by default. This applies both to text output in cells and to the output of `display()`. I would trust `.count()`.

Regarding your second question, there are four types of places you can save on Databricks:

1. To Hive-managed tables using `df.write.saveAsTable()`. These will end up in an S3 bucket managed by Databricks, which is mounted to `/user/hive/warehouse`. Note that you will not have access to the AWS credentials to work with that bucket. However, you can use the Databricks file utilities (`dbutils.fs.*`) or the Hadoop filesystem APIs to work with the files, should you need to.
2. Local SSD storage. This is best done with `persist()` or `cache()` but, if you really need to, you can write to, for example, `/tmp` using `df.write.save("/dbfs/tmp/...")`.
3. Your own S3 buckets, which you need to mount.
4. To `/FileStore/`, which is the only "directory" you can download from directly from your cluster. This is useful, for example, for writing CSV files you want to bring into Excel immediately. You write the file and output a "Download File" HTML link into your notebook.

For more details see the [Databricks FileSystem Guide](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/01%20Databricks%20Overview/10%20Databricks%20File%20System%20-%20DBFS.html).

Answer (score 2):

The difference could be bad source data. Spark is lazy by nature so it's not going to build a bunch columns and fill them in just to count rows. So the data may not parse when you actually execute against it or the rows or null. Or your schema doesn't allow nulls for certain columns and they are null when the data is fully parsed. Or you are modifying the data between your count, collect and show. There is just not enough detail to tell for sure. you can open up a spark shell and create a small piece of data and test those conditions by turning that data into a dataframe. Change the schema to allow and not allow nulls or add nulls in source data and not nulls. make the source data string but make the schema require integers.

As far as saving your data frame. you create a dataframe writer with write and then define the file type you want to save it as and then the file name. This example saves a parquet file. There are many other options for filetype and write options that are permitted here.

```
df.write.parquet("s3://myfile")
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. I think your answer to my second question is spot on. For the first question, I'm still not sure. There is no other action that I take between the count and the println/show. The data seems to be fine -- it prints OK (if missing some rows) and saves OK. The saved data in fact does have 5460 rows.

Comment: Also, given that the number of rows differ depending on whether I ask for foreach println or show, I suspect it's related to some bug of Databricks, in particular the size of the output cell.